# When are \space tokens discarded?

Tags: tex-core, white-space

Consider this example:

```
\obeyspaces
 b
\bye
```

The output is `b`.

Why is the `\space` discarded?
It is not discarded during pre-processing because it has catcode 13 - it is discarded during tokenization, before getting to stomach. Compare:

```
\obeyspaces\let =a
 b
\bye
```

The output is `ab`.

In which place in *TeXbook* are these rules described?

Comment: it's just `\space b
\bye`

Comment: @touhami No, it's just `b`. Add new paragraph and compare alignment.

Comment: Not sure about the TeXBook, but take a look at section 2.10.3 of [TeX by Topic](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/texbytopic).

Comment: @IgorLiferenko i mean your code is equivalent to `\space b \bye`

Comment: which after expansion becomes ` b \bye`. so it's just a space. You can see page 282 in TeXBook.

Comment: Leading spaces at the beginning of a paragraph are absorbed.  `b` is the first character of the paragraph.  For example, try "          b   c", even with `\obeyspaces`. (Sorry can't make markup do what I want...many spaces before and after `b`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\obeyspaces` works in horizontal mode.  In your examples, you are in vertical mode until the first printing character is reached.  If you add `\leavevmode` to the first line, the spaces will be realized.

In essence, the leading spaces at the beginning of a paragraph are absorbed, because you are in vertical mode.

```
{\obeyspaces
 b}

\obeyspaces\leavevmode
 b

\obeyspaces\leavevmode    %
 b

{\obeyspaces\let =a
 b}

{\obeyspaces\let =a\leavevmode %
 b}

\bye
```

[image]